# Взаимодействие PHP и MySql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formhtml</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="cucak" method="post" action="action.php">
                Name:<br>
                <input name="name" type="text" size="25"><br>
                Surname:<br>
                <input name="surname" type="text" size="25"><br>
                Email:<br>
                <input name="email" type="text" size="25"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Ok">
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Это моя `html` форма.

```
<html>
<head><title>Formhtml</title></head>
</html>
<?php 
    $db_hostname='localhost';
    $db_database='formtest';
    $db_username='root';
    $db_password='';
    $db_server=mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if(!$db_server) die ("unable to connect mysql:".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("unable to select database".mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['name']))
        $Name=$_POST['name'];   
    if(isset($_POST['surname']))
        $Surname=$_POST['surname']; 
    if(isset($_POST['email']))
        $Email=$_POST['email']; 
    echo "Your name is: $Name<br/>
    Your surname is: $Surname<br/>
    Your email is: $Email<br/>";
    $query="INSERT INTO basa(name, surname, email) VALUES('$Name','$Surname','$Email')";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result) die("error to connect date base: ".mysql_error());
        $fh=fopen("textfile.txt",'a+') or die("file didn't create");
        $text="
        Your name is: $Name
        Your surname is: $Surname
        Your email is: $Email";
        fwrite($fh,$text) or die("error");
        fclose($fh);

;?>
```

А это программа `action.php`. Как можно отобразить файлы базы данных в виде списка на странице обозревателя?

Comment: Исправьте содержимое, уберите грамматические ошибки, отделите текст от кода, переформулируйте. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: и поясните нормально что значит - "Как можно отобразить файлы базы данных в виде списка на странице обозревателя" а именно что такое тут - "файлы базы данных"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присоединяюсь, сформируйте нормально вопрос пожалуйста...
Но рискну проявить екстрасенсорные способности

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
$data = array() // создаем массив чтобы в него положить результат mysql выборки
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //функция mysql_query возвращает данные типа resource,
    //соответственно нам необходимо преобразовать их в данные
    //с которыми можно работать, например в массив
    //о функции mysql_fetch_assoc() можете почитать на php.net
    //мне лениво так все описывать
    $data[] = $row;
}
//теперь в массиве $data у нас лежит результат выборки с БД
// ну собственно что вы с этими данными будете делать дело ваше
//для примера расспечатаем
print_r($data);
```

если это не то о чем вы спрашивали - перепишите нормально вопрос, я ответил так как понял